# How to mock MUI5 Pro license key in Jest tests for React components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, vite, mui-x

I'm currently integrating MUI v5 Pro components into my React library and then import those library components into my host app. I have set up the MUI license key in the `.env` file of both the library and the host app, and I'm importing the necessary components like so:

```js
import { LicenseInfo } from "@mui/x-license-pro";

LicenseInfo.setLicenseKey(import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP__MUI_KEY || "");
```

However, when I execute my Jest and React Library tests, I encounter a "missing license key" issue, even though the key is correctly set in the .env files.

```
console.error
    *************************************************************
    
    MUI: Missing license key.
    
    The license key is missing. You might not be allowed to use `@mui/x-date-pickers-pro` which is part of MUI X Pro.
    
    To solve the issue, you can check the free trial conditions: https://mui.com/r/x-license-trial.
    If you are eligible no actions are required. If you are not eligible to the free trial, you need to purchase a license https://mui.com/r/x-get-license or stop using the software immediately.
    
    *************************************************************
```

To complicate matters, not every developer on our team has access to this license key—primarily only front-end developers. Therefore, I want to ensure that the tests pass on every local machine, whether or not a developer has set the license key.

Is there a way to mock or bypass the license check only during Jest and React Library tests, ensuring they execute without requiring the key?

Comment: This works for me if i directly use the string literal in the test. e.g. `LicenseInfo.setLicenseKey(
  '5c0f4060e52f....)` So guess your issue is specific to the env import

Answer (score 2):

Within the jest setup file, mock the MUI license returns. This should remove those console errors shown while testing with jest:

```
jest.mock('@mui/x-license-pro', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('@mui/x-license-pro'),
    useLicenseVerifier: () => 'Valid',
    Watermark: () => null,
})):
```

Alternatively, mocking this in your test suite's `beforeAll(() => {})` also works if you don't need to mock it for all tests